# Design client - data base - server

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that my title, ain't concrete but I don't know what exaclly it is called. The thing is i have to do for the university a project where more people are taking part and we simulate a team work enviorment(agile).

I am in charge with the design for the `database - applicaion communication`. The server part more exactly. Where i need to manage the concurrency if it is the case, and all the rest of the things I'm about to find out.

I would like some hints or tutotials regarding this part of an application, best practices and stuff. The technologie we decided on is `java` with `hibernate`. I am familiar with ado.net basics and ruby on rails when it comes to something alike.

Comment: ofc, but there are many tutorials, and from my experience not all the tutorials are the best, so  I'm asking for something that is recommandet by others that are familiar with this domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate guys have written a [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/), I'd recommend going through that one as a start.